# R: Reading in txt files from path and appending ID to list element using lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I am reading in data from txt files from a path on my harddrive (all on different locations) which I get from a dataframe `df`

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, path = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("C:/temp/TestA.txt","C:/temp/TestD/bla.txt", "C:/temp/TestZ/name1.txt"), class = "factor"), metadata = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("dummy", "test1", "UU_QQ", "ZZZ_TTT"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "path", "metadata"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

id                    path metadata
1  1       C:/temp/TestA.txt    test1
2  2 C:/temp/TestZ/name1.txt    dummy
3  3       C:/temp/TestA.txt  ZZZ_TTT
4  4   C:/temp/TestD/bla.txt    UU_QQ
```

I am reading in the data into a list the following way using `lapply`

```
data_list <- lapply(df$path, read.table, sep=";", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, fileEncoding="latin1")
```

How could I also include the `id` parameter into the new list?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
data_list <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){
   data_list <- read.table(df$path[i], sep=";", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, fileEncoding="latin1")
   data_list$id <- df$id[i]
   return(data_list)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `Map` with `cbind`.  We pass the `list` of `data.frames` (`lapply(...)`) and the 'id' column as arguments to `Map`, use `cbind` as the `FUN` to create corresponding 'id' column for each `data.frame` in the `list`.

```
data_list <- Map(cbind, lapply(df$path, read.table, sep=";", 
                header=TRUE,fill=TRUE, fileEncoding='Latin1'), id=df$id)
```